# powerquery - sumproduct or if clause with more than one case

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to remove the rows of the data within powerquery where I find the duplicates. I need to delete the rows where `sumproduct` is 1.

[Example File (Updated)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxC6zZIYn1SzNzNKY3VSR0FybFU)

To be more specific I wrote a `sumproduct` formula in Excel which will tell my target more clearly. I am sure there is a way around...

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: i have a table and i want to match the rows where H column equals to I column and A column equals to B column and C column and also G column must be matching... 

i uploaded more clear updated file...

Comment: Your comment and updated file just add confusion - there's no obvious relevance to your original question.  This is clearly a waste of time ...

Comment: @MikeHoney  i will soon upload the solution , just testing it right with different data variations... but i had to make 4 more tables to solve the problem... but with some programming skills, i am sure there is an easier way...

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot at what I *think* you're after.

If you start with your spreadsheet, then select it all and click the "Power Query" tab and "From Table/Range" button:

[image]

Then change this...

[image]

...to this (*because your first cell is A1 and your last cell is J15*):

[image]

...and click OK to load make your spreadsheet selection into a table and load it into Power Query.

You'll now see Power Query open up, loaded with your table:

[image]

Now, I assume you want to find and remove duplicate information...which appears to be rows 3 & 13 and rows 5 & 14 (although formats are different, the information looks the same).

Click the dropdown arrow at the top right of the "Tarih" column, then deselect "(null)" and "Tarih" in the list:

[image]

...and clik OK. You'll see your null filled rows and duplicate column titles disappear.

Then select the "Tarih" column, and then the "Transform" tab, and then the "Data Type:", and then "Date" to change the format of the column so it is all the same date format:

[image]

Then select the "Borc", "Alacak", and "Column1" columns, and then the "Transform" tab, and then the "Data Type:", and then "Decimal Number" to change the format of the column so it is all the same number format. (*You'll get errors...it's okay.*)

Select the "Borc" and "Alacak" columns, and then the "Transform" tab, and then the down-arrow to the right of "Replace Values", and then "Replace Errors":

[image]

Enter zero in the "Value" box and click OK. (The errors will change to zeroes.)

Then click the [image] in the upper left corner of the table, then click the "Home" tab, and then the "Remove Rows" button, and then the "Remove Duplicates":

[image]

The last two rows will be removed because they are duplicates:[image]